# My web build not working when I use useState

Tags: react-native

I was following a tutorial on how to change text with buttons in react native and it use useState

When I tried it, it didn't display any errors but when told to compile on web it just showed a white screen

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
    const [outputText, setOutputText] = useState("You can replace this text")
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Text>{outputText}</Text>
          <Button title="Replace" onPress={() => setOutputText('The text changed!')} color="#57a9af" />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
} 

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#d6f0f2',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: your written code is not proper actually u mixed both Class components and Functional components at a time. follow this link to check how to write Functional components https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-function-component/

Answer (score 0):

```html
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

const App = ()  => {

    const [outputText, setOutputText] = useState("You can replace this text")
    
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Text>{outputText}</Text>
          <Button title="Replace" onPress={() => setOutputText('The text changed!')} color="#57a9af" />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
} 
export default App;
```